# Array of instances: Transform one specific value, in each instance, return a new array

Tags: arrays, swift, struct

```
struct Person {
    var name: String
    var age: Int
    var weight : Int
    var shoeSize: Int
}


struct Group {
    var members : [Person]
}

let mygroup = Group(members: [
    Person(name: "Billy", age: 59, weight: 170, shoeSize: 9),
    Person(name: "Jacob", age: 19, weight: 130, shoeSize: 11),
    Person(name: "Zara", age: 25, weight: 320, shoeSize: 10)
])
```

How can I multiple each age by 2, and return a new array (myGroupV2), but leave the other elements untouched?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of individually assigning all the properties of `Person`, you can simply create a new `Person` instance and change its `age` property, i.e.

```
let myGroupV2 = mygroup.members.map {(person) -> Person in
    var person = person
    person.age *= 2
    return person
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You simply need to use `map` to apply a closure to each element of an `Array`. In your `map` closure, you need to initialise a new `Person` instance, where all inputs are the same as the properties of the original `Person`, except for `age`, which you multiply by 2.

```
let myGroup2 = Group(members: mygroup.members.map { Person(name: $0.name, age: $0.age * 2, weight: $0.weight, shoeSize: $0.shoeSize) })
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you need it more than once, an extention can also be helpful:

```
extension Person {
    var asDoubleAged: Person {
        get {
            return Person(name: self.name, age: self.age * 2, weight: self.weight, shoeSize: self.shoeSize)
        }
    }
}

let myGroupV2 = Group(members: mygroup.members.map { $0.asDoubleAged })
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let personArray = mygroup.members.map { p in Person(name: p.name, age: p.age*2, weight: p.weight, shoeSize: p.shoeSize) }

let mygroup2=Group(members: personArray)
```

#### or

```
let mygroup2 = Group(members: mygroup.members.map { Person(name: $0.name, age: $0.age*2, weight: $0.weight, shoeSize: $0.shoeSize)})
```

Comment: What is the difference from David's answer?